# Interfacing a Rotary Encoder with an HID device (STM32)

Tags: embedded, stm32, hid, stm32f4, stm32cubeide

I’m trying to create a rotary encoder device that will output a set of keypresses depending on whether I turn it forward or backward, but as of now am confused as to whether it just using a scroll wheel descriptor, interfacing the encoder as you would normally and creating an input report based on the keypresses, or if there’s more. In my approach, I’m trying to interface the encoder with my STM32 in the timer encoder mode, where the hardware counts for me, and depending on whether it’s increasing or decreasing, I output a set of keypresses, but I’m not sure if this is the correct way.

Comment: Since you have invented this application and it is not standard functionality on an HID, there is no "correct way", so you question is a matter of opinion and therefore not a valid question on SO.  If you have a problem making it work, that would be a legitimate question.

Comment: @Clifford but isn’t this basically a scroll wheel on a mouse? Afaik, scroll wheels are included but I haven’t been able to find any clear documentation.

Comment: a scroll wheel generates counted pulses that are processed by the host. You are proposing (it seems) to emit a sequence of key presses. As an HID device that is the behaviour of a keyboard not a scroll wheel. It is not clear why you would do that rather than emitting wheel messages, but your choice.

Comment: I want to scrub through the timeline of a video editing software using a scroll wheel. However, the shortcuts for this in the software are KJ to scrub backwards and KL to move forward. Maybe there is another way to implement this with HID and an encoder? I’m a lot more familiar with hardware than with software, but I’d like to learn.

Comment: I still think there is no "correct way". Such a thing is normally called a "keyboard wedge" and is used for such things as barcode scanners for POS applications, where the barcode is emitted "as if" the code digits were typed. Your solution is appropriate, but as it stands is too broad and opinion based to stand as an SO question. Ask about issues you have implementing your solution rather than if it is a good solution.